# In Jasper Reports table showing only one page of data

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to jasper Reports. using table component in reports. while executing query in data source i am getting complete data but In jasper Reports table showing only one page of data.remaining pages not displaying. pls give me a solution.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more whether you have any parameters or not or post your JRXML?

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you scroll on the next page?
2) If at 1 the answer is yes, then try to put your table on Summary band